# Default JsonNetSerializer does not camel case property names

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm injecting a custom serializer using NEST.JsonNetSerializer like this

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connPool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default);
```

When I was using the built in serializer it camel cased the property names for me (from snake case) automatically. How can I make the custom serializer work the same way? I see that I can use `ConnectionSettings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` to specify how property names are inferred. But it seems unneccessary to copy the NEST code to make it work as before.

The only reason I'm not using the built-in serializer is because I have to work with dynamic models, and the internal JSON.NET objects in NEST are inaccessible.